# Program compiled with vs2012 runs slower than on vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, random

I have a simple piece of code that generates random graphs by considering all possible edges and randomly selecting which ones to add to a file (based on a parameter p - the chance for each edge to be added). The algorithm looks like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodeCount; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned int j = i+1; j < nodeCount; ++j)
    {
        uniform_int_distribution<> d(0, 999999);
        int randNum = d(randEngine);
        if (randNum < p * 1000000)
        {
            //code that adds the edge to the file
        }
    }
}
```

I used to compile this code on vs2010, and when creating graphs with 50000 nodes and p=0.00002 it took ~26 seconds. I now upgraded to vs2012, compiled, and I get ~74 seconds! Almost triple the time!

I isolated the part that runs slower - it seems to be the random number generation (I commented out the code that is not included above, which writes to the file, and the same times were recorded).

The project definitions are exactly the same (except for the platform - vs100 vs. vs110). Any ideas why the random number generator has become so much worse in VS2012?? Or is it me that's doing something wrong?

Either way - what can I do except for going back to vs2010...?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be that the newer compiler uses a better and more time-intensive PRNG!

Comment: What about the standard [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function?

Comment: It is unclear what engine you are using, "randEngine" doesn't help.

Comment: Oops sorry didn't realize it was missing. It's: minstd_rand randEngine(time(NULL));

Comment: I suggest doing two things to try to get to the bottom of this: inspect and compare the generated assembly code for this code snippet, and to replace the random number generation with something simpler that you know is behaving exactly the same on both versions (e.g. `rand()` or even some throwaway code you write yourself for testing purposes.) Specially with comparing the generated assembly, you (or someone here) should be able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: debug or release build? perhaps the new compiler performs more runtime checks?

Comment: So I dug in a little deeper... Seems like it is the uniform_int_distribution that's taking longer on VS2012. Going over the source code it does seem different, although I still haven't figured out what changed. But running: "int randNum = randEngine();" instead of "int randNum = d(randEngine);" takes ~1750 milliseconds on *both* VS2010 and VS2010, however when using "d(randEngine)" while VS2010 goes up to only ~2000 ms, VS2012 jumps to ~5900 ms!! Same type of thing happens when I use a generator that's simply a wrapper to rand().